# Unable to call a scala object in a switch case in java

Tags: java

I want to call an object written in Scala in a switch case block in java, but I get an error:

```
case expressions must be constant expressions
```

The object in scala is:

```
object Test {
   val A = "a"
   val B = "b"
}
```

And in java I have the following code block:

```
String op = "a"
switch(op) {
   case Test.A(): System.out.println("A"); break;
   case Test.B(): System.out.println("B"); break;
}
```

`Test.A` translated in java would be `public static final A`, so I don't have any idea why the compiler compains.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Test.A`  and `Test.B` to refer variables, `Test.A()` refers to a method

Comment: If I only call Test.A in java I get Test.A cannot be resolved to a type, but if I use Test.A() it works..